# C++, templates with parameters, redefined operator = and pointers assignment

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, assignment-operator

There is a class Test:

```
typedef enum
{
    AA, BB
} TType;

template <typename T>
struct TVector
{
    typedef std::vector <T> Type;
};

template < typename T, const TType type >
class Test
{
private:
            typename TVector <T>::Type it; 
};
```

and its specialization with redefined operator = (there with no additional functionality):

```
template < typename T, const TType type >
class Test <T *, type> 
{
public:
    Test <T *, type > & operator = ( const Test <T*, type > &source ) {return *this;}

            template <TType type2>
    Test <T *, type > & operator = ( const Test <T*, type2 > &source ){return *this;}

            template <TType type2>
    Test <T *, type > * operator = ( const Test <T*, type2 > *source ) {return *this;}
};
```

I am trying to assign objects with different TType parameter each other, and this step works correctly.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
Test <double *, AA> a1;
Test <double *, BB> b1;

a1=b1;  //Correct

Test <double *, AA> *a2;
Test <double *, BB> *b2;

a2 = b2;  //Error

return 0;
}
```

But the same step with pointers does not work, see the error code:

```
Error   1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'Test<T,type> *' to 'Test<T,type> *' 49
```

Is it possible to assign pointers with different TType parameter each other (how?) or not?

**Updated question:**

And what about assignment between pointers and objects?

```
a2 = &b1;  //Error
*a2 = b1;  //Unitialized memory
```

Could I ask for a code sample?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second example does not work because you are not assigning *to the object*, you are assigning *to a pointer*.  It's the same reason that this does not work:

```
int * a;
float * b;

b = a;
```

Even though a `float` can be assigned from an `int`, *a pointer to `float` cannot be assigned from a pointer to `int`*.

Try `*a2 = b2` or `*a2 = *b2` instead -- your operators should catch both of those.

Note also that this implementation appears to be wrong:

```
template <TType type2>
Test <T *, type > * operator = ( const Test <T*, type2 > *source )
{
    return *this;
}
```

The `this` implicit variable is already a pointer type, so you need to `return this`, not `return *this`.  I would suggest eliminating this overload of the assignment operator completely, since it is bound to be more confusing than it will be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... But *a2 = *b2 could time-consuming if the vector contains a large data. This is the reason why I wanted to pass only pointers....

Comment: @justik But if you assign to `a2` directly, you are assigning to a pointer.  If you use references, `*a2 = *b2` will be just as performant anyway; it's not going to run any faster using pointers instead of references.  It may be a bit faster to type, but that's the only benefit.  Further, assigning one pointer to another causing actual object assignment will be confusing to seasoned C++ developers, who will expect it to just copy the pointer.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis I have no idea what you are asking, nor how it relates to the question at hand.

Comment: @cdhowie sorry I didn't looked at the example properly I guess that's why had asked weird question